# Special term for a cycle containing a single vertex and edge

Tags: graphs, terminology

Is there a special term for a cycle containing a single vertex and edge?  I feel like I read "self-cycle" somewhere, but can't find where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is generally called a [Self Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)).

It refers to an edge that connects a vertex to itself.